# Why are singleton_class objects frozen in Ruby 2.4 but not in 2.3?

Tags: ruby, sequel, ruby-2.4

We have an app that uses the Sequel gem to connect to a data source, perform some work, and then return a result which has a number of convenience methods attached to the `singleton_class` of that object.  In ruby 2.3, this code is working as expected:

```
result = EpulseDB::Employee.where(normalized_args)
result.singleton_class.include(EpulseNormalization)
```

And we can see using ruby 2.3.4 the singleton_class is not frozen:

```
[1] pry(main)> result = EpulseDB::Employee.where(employee_id: 2)
=> #<Sequel::Postgres::Dataset: "SELECT * FROM \"employee\" WHERE (\"employee_id\" = 2)">
[2] pry(main)> result.frozen?
=> true
[3] pry(main)> result.singleton_class.frozen?
=> false
[4] pry(main)> result.singleton_class.include(EpulseNormalization)
=> #<Class:#<Sequel::Postgres::Dataset:0x007feff0903660>>
```

But in Ruby 2.4.2 it appears the `singleton_class` is being returned as frozen and we can no longer extend it.  Is there a new way of extending the singleton that I should be using??

```
[1] pry(main)> result = EpulseDB::Employee.where(employee_id: 2)
=> #<Sequel::Postgres::Dataset: "SELECT * FROM \"employee\" WHERE (\"employee_id\" = 2)">
[2] pry(main)> result.frozen?
=> true
[3] pry(main)> result.singleton_class.frozen?
=> true
[4] pry(main)> result.singleton_class.include(EpulseNormalization)
RuntimeError: can't modify frozen object
from (pry):4:in `append_features'
```

Comment: If this is the same version of Sequel it could be a shift in how Ruby handles these things.

Comment: Exactly - nothing changes except for switching for Ruby 2.3.4 to 2.4.2. I use RVM and switch between them.

Comment: It looks like a bug in Ruby 2.3 that was fixed in 2.4.

Comment: @JörgWMittag do you have a reference to that bug or are you speculating?

Comment: Just a guess. Being able to modify the singleton class of a frozen object pretty much negates the idea of being "frozen" IMO, so, it seems clear to me that the singleton class of a frozen object must be frozen also. [It looks like that is specified behavior](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/test/ruby/test_class.rb#L442-L449).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Dataset#with_extend` to return a modified copy of the dataset extended with a module, instead of calling `Dataset#extend` to modify the dataset itself.  This works on all versions of ruby that Sequel supports.

Backstory: This is not related to Ruby itself, it's due to a workaround in Sequel for the lack of a feature in Ruby <2.4.

In Ruby <2.4, `Object#freeze` can't handle cases where `Object#clone` is used to create modified copies of frozen objects (including copies of the object's singleton class).  Ruby 2.4 added the `freeze: false` option to `Object#clone` to allow creating modified copies of frozen objects including their singleton class (see https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12300).

Sequel::Dataset uses `#clone` internally to return modified datasets, and it's required the datasets include copies of any singleton classes used for proper functioning.  Since I wanted Sequel::Dataset to be frozen, but still work on ruby < 2.4, it basically fakes being frozen on ruby <2.4.  It's only truly frozen in ruby 2.4.  See:

- https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/5.3.0/lib/sequel/dataset/query.rb#L74-L105
- https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/5.3.0/lib/sequel/dataset/misc.rb#L72-L88

Comment: thanks for all the detail here, the `with_extend` method is exactly what I needed!